# API Gateway with Microservices and Application API with Fallback Controller

Tags: .net, angular, microservices, api-gateway, ocelot

I'm creating an application which will be connected to microservices (shared inside company).

Attached screen shows a little of planned architecture
[App architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ard3I.png)
As you can see API Gateway (created with Ocelot) will provide easy and quick access point for all endpoints
from Microservices and Application API endpoints. Application API will also have `FallbackController` which will return a View of builded Angular app. And this Angular app will be using Gateway API endpoints.
**Is this a good approach or should I consider a different one?**
For ease of use, I'll explain how it's supposed to work during development:

Angular application will be available on: `https:localhost:2137`

Application API Swagger docs will be available on: `https:localhost:2137/swagger/index.html`

Whole solution will contain `GatewayAPI`, `Application API` and `Angular app`.

Application API will be responsible for providing endpoints that will allow to build a specific logic of this solution.

Builded Angular app, located inside this project (`Gateway API` + `Application API` + `Angular app`), will be using Gateway API endpoints to work. [Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3pYk.png)
Angular will create requests to Gateway API to access Application API endpoints and Microservices API endpoints, but in itself it will be available within the Application (from `FallbackController`).
I'm trying to get as much experience as I can, so I will be able to change my current job for something better :D **Please, tell me whether what I wrote makes sense or not** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea you can do it like this, but I usually separate the Angular App, the Application API and the Gateway API into separate Microservices for better separation of concerns and the other benefits of that pattern.

Comment: Thanks a million!
Correct me if I'm wrong, but in that scenario CORS Policy should be placed inside of Gateway API project. Am I right, or there is other approach to do that?

Comment: There are 3 ways that I've used to avoid CORS problems. 1: Set the CORS policy as you say. 2: Route traffic to the other Microservices through a proxy in the same backend that serves the frontend project, for local development there is a proxy functionally built into webpack that I usually use, for the production environment use path-based routing in your network layer. 3: Dedicate a Microservices for routing to all other Microservices, both those internal to the application and any external dependencies. My preference about these options in falling order from best to worse is: 2, 3, 1.